# Why does "dpkg --instdir=dir/ -i xxx.deb" also set the administrative directory to "dir", like the "--root=ddd" option does?

Tags: command-line, package-management, software-installation, dpkg, debian

I was using Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS. I have made a file called `helloworld.deb`, Its source file structure is as follows:

```
helloworld
├── DEBIAN
│   └── control
└── usr
    └── games
        └── mygame.sh
```

I used `dpkg-deb --build helloworld` to make the`helloworld.deb` file. Then I used `sudo dpkg --instdir=phonyRoot -i helloworld.deb` to install it in a folder called `phonyRoot`.

I executed `tree phonyRoot` and got the following:

```
phonyRoot
├── usr
│   └── games
│       └── mygame.sh
└── var
    └── lib
        └── dpkg
            ├── info
            │   ├── format
            │   ├── helloworld.list
            │   └── helloworld.md5sums
            ├── lock
            ├── lock-frontend
            ├── status
            ├── status-old
            ├── triggers
            │   ├── Lock
            │   └── Unincorp
            └── updates

8 directories, 10 files
```

Then I executed `dpkg -l | grep helloworld`, but couldn't get any information about the package I just installed.

As shown above, the `--instdir=phonyRoot` also changed the administrative directory to `phonyRoot` folder. It seems that the option `--admindir=dir` is also added under the hood. According to [the manual](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/jammy/man1/dpkg.1.html), this is the same behavior as the `--root=dir` option.

Why does the behavior of `--instdir=dir` not match the description in the manual?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

#### In Brief

There seems to be an issue in DPKG prior to version `1.22.0` (which comes with Ubuntu 23.10) and that can be fixed by explicitly setting the environment variable `DPKG_ADMINDIR` on the command line like so:

```
sudo DPKG_ADMINDIR="/var/lib/dpkg" dpkg --instdir=...
```

#### In Detail

`--instdir`, actually, doesn't seem to do that by itself ... Please see the demonstration below:

```
$tree myapp/
myapp/
├── DEBIAN
│   ├── control
│   └── install
└── usr
    └── bin
        └── myap

4 directories, 3 files
$
$
$tree dir
dir

0 directories, 0 files
$
$
$head myapp/{DEBIAN,usr/bin}/*
==> myapp/DEBIAN/control <==
Package: myapp
Version: 0.01
Architecture: all
Maintainer: my contact
Section: extras
Priority: optional
Homepage: my homepage
Description: myapp description

==> myapp/DEBIAN/install <==
myapp usr/bin/

==> myapp/usr/bin/myap <==
#!/bin/bash

printf '%s\n' {1..9}
$
$
$dpkg --version
Debian 'dpkg' package management program version 1.22.0 (amd64).
This is free software; see the GNU General Public License version 2 or
later for copying conditions. There is NO warranty.
$
$
$dpkg -b myapp/
dpkg-deb: building package 'myapp' in 'myapp.deb'.
$
$
$sudo dpkg --instdir=dir -i myapp.deb 
Selecting previously unselected package myapp.
(Reading database ... 217181 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack myapp.deb ...
Unpacking myapp (0.01) ...
Setting up myapp (0.01) ...
$
$
$tree dir
dir
└── usr
    └── bin
        └── myap

3 directories, 1 file
$
$
$./dir/usr/bin/myap 
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
$
$
$dpkg -s myapp
Package: myapp
Status: install ok installed
Priority: optional
Section: extras
Maintainer: my contact
Architecture: all
Version: 0.01
Description: myapp description
Homepage: my homepage
$
$
$dpkg --root=dir -l
$
```

**Notice** `(Reading database ... 217181 files and directories currently installed.)` as it's reading from the original system-wide default `admindir` at `/var/lib/dpkg` and hence the large number `217181` ... In fact it shouldn't do that as explicitly stated by `dpkg -b --help`:

```
--instdir=<directory>      Change installation dir without changing admin dir.
```

While, `--root` does:

```
$tree dir2
dir2

0 directories, 0 files
$
$
$sudo dpkg --root=dir2 -i myapp.deb 
Selecting previously unselected package myapp.
(Reading database ... 0 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack myapp.deb ...
Unpacking myapp (0.01) ...
Setting up myapp (0.01) ...
$
$
$tree dir2
dir2
├── usr
│   └── bin
│       └── myap
└── var
    └── lib
        └── dpkg
            ├── info
            │   ├── format
            │   ├── myapp.install
            │   ├── myapp.list
            │   └── myapp.md5sums
            ├── lock
            ├── lock-frontend
            ├── status
            ├── status-old
            ├── triggers
            │   ├── Lock
            │   └── Unincorp
            └── updates

9 directories, 11 files
$
$
$./dir2/usr/bin/myap 
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
$
$
$dpkg --root=dir2 -l
Desired=Unknown/Install/Remove/Purge/Hold
| Status=Not/Inst/Conf-files/Unpacked/halF-conf/Half-inst/trig-aWait/Trig-pend
|/ Err?=(none)/Reinst-required (Status,Err: uppercase=bad)
||/ Name           Version      Architecture Description
+++-==============-============-============-=================================
ii  myapp          0.01         all          myapp description
$
```

**Notice** `(Reading database ... 0 files and directories currently installed.)` as it's reading from the alternate `admindir` at `dir2/var/lib/dpkg` and hence the number `0`.

As stated in [`man dpkg`](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/en/man1/dpkg.1.html):

```
--root=dir
       Changing root changes instdir to dir and admindir to dir/var/lib/dpkg.
```

... which it does, but:

```
--instdir=dir
      Change  default installation directory which refers to the directory where packages
      are to be installed. instdir is also  the  directory  passed  to  chroot(2)  before
      running package's installation scripts, which means that the scripts see instdir as
      a root directory.  (Defaults to /)
```

... doesn't appear to change `admindir` but rather changes the root directory for the package's installation scripts, so probably look into those in your package if any or for something related or something else.

That said, `--instdir`'s behavior, although may not be necessarily documented directly under its description in the manual, but might depend on whether the environment variable `DPKG_ADMINDIR` is set or not ... Quoting from [`diff from 1.21.1ubuntu2 to 1.21.7ubuntu1`](http://launchpadlibrarian.net/600875727/dpkg_1.21.1ubuntu2_1.21.7ubuntu1.diff.gz):

```
+    man: Clarify --admindir and --instdir default values
+    
+    These depend on the DPKG_ADMINDIR and DPKG_ROOT environment variables
+    being set or not. Although this is mentioned in the ENVIRONMENT section
+    it is not obvious directly from the command-line options descriptions.
```

... and you can see that in action (in DPKG versions prior to `1.22.0`) if you ensure that environment variable is properly set by for example explicitly setting it on the command line itself like:

```
sudo DPKG_ADMINDIR="/var/lib/dpkg" dpkg --instdir=dir -i myapp.deb
```

This, however, seems to be fixed as per the above demonstration using DPKG version `1.22.0` which is the default under Ubuntu 23.10.

Comment: I'm using Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS, dpkg version 1.21.1 (amd64). I repeated your actions, but the thing I got from `sudo dpkg --instdir=dir -i myapp.deb` is "(Reading database ... 0 files and directories currently installed.)" and it still create "dir/var/lib/dpkg/*". I suspect the difference is caused by the version of dpkg and the ubuntun system. I don't know how to upgrade dpkg on my system, because the `sudo apt upgrade dpkg`  command says "dpkg is already the newest version (1.21.1ubuntu2.2).". Which system and version are you using?

Comment: @cosmosben Ah, it could be some issue specific to some version. I will look into that when I get a chance (hopefully today) and update the answer with extra info  … Meanwhile, the demonstration above is done on Ubuntu 23.10 so try that from a 23.10 live USB before you attempt to upgrade.

Comment: I think the issue is caused by the version of Ubuntu and dpkg, I have just tried  the `sudo dpkg --instdir=dir -i myapp.deb`  command on both Ubutu 23.10.1 with dpkg version 1.22.0 (amd64) and Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS with dpkg version 1.21.1 (amd64). The former behaved as you described in your answer, the latter behaved as I described in my question.

Comment: Sorry, just saw your edited answer. I just ran the `echo $DPKG_ADMINDIR` command on both Ubuntu and dpkg versions and got an empty value. Therefore, the environment variable DPKG_ADMINDIR is not set on either version when I executed when I excuted `sudo dpkg --instdir=dir -i myapp.deb`.

Comment: @cosmos It seems to not be, basically, only about whether `DPKG_ADMINDIR` is set or not but, rather, in addition, how DPKG handles the unset `DPKG_ADMINDIR` when `--instdir=dir` is passed as an option ... That, however seems to be fixed in DPKG version `1.22.0`.